# Probability distribution of resampled quantile

Tags: random-variables, quantile

There is a list $X$ of $N$ different numbers, sorted in ascending order. First, we perform resampling with replacement, constructing a list $Y$. This means that we consider a uniform distribution over the elements of $X$, and sample from that distribution $N$ times, forming the list $Y$. Note that $Y$ will likely contain multiple copies of some elements of $X$, and some other elements will be absent.

- For example, if $X = [1,2,3,4,5,6]$, then $Y$ could be any combination of the above, for example $Y = [6,4,6,1,1,3]$

**Question**: What is the probability that the j-th smallest element of $X$ is also the i-th smallest element of $Y$.

- For example, if $Y$ is the one above and we are looking for the 2nd smallest element of $Y$ (i.e. $i = 2$), its value would be 1, which means that it is the 1st smallest element of $X$ (i.e. $j = 1$) in this particular random outcome for $Y$.

**Note**: If you find an analytic solution, that's cool. However, it is sufficient to find an algorithm that requires a finite amount of operations.

**Edit**: I have performed a simulation for N=20 doing 10000 resamples. It appears that the target probability is somewhat similar to a gaussian $e^{(i-j)^2}$, but not quite, as the standard deviation is wider in the center than at the edges. The function appears symmetric in $i$ and $j$, which does not seem trivial to me.

[image: The probability distribution]

Here I also plot the log10 of the distribution to see the tails better. The white squares are NAN due to finite number of samples taken

[image: The logarithm of the distribution]

Comment: "First, we perform resampling without replacement, constructing a list $Y$
'', and then you go on to say that $Y$
 may contain duplicates...

Comment: @stochastic-conch typo, thanks

Answer (score 3):

For $k\in1...n$, each $Y_k$ is sampled uniformly and independently from $X$ with replacement. Define a [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) with 3 mutually exclusive events whose probabilities sum to 1:

- $Y_k<X_j$, which occurs with probability $\frac{j-1}{n}$
- $Y_k=X_j$, which occurs with probability $\frac{1}{n}$
- $Y_k>X_j$, which occurs with probability $\frac{n-j}{n}$

To illustrate, consider $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Using $j=3$, a sample resulting in $Y=\{1,5,5,3,5\}$ corresponds to the following multinomial random vector, $z$:

\begin{array}{c|c|c}
 Y_k<X_{\{j\}} & Y_k=X_{\{j\}} & Y_k>X_{\{j\}}\\\hline
 z_1=1 & z_2=1 & z_3=3
\end{array}

The probability of occurrence of $z=[1,1,3]$ is

$$\frac{n!}{z_1!z_2!z_3!}\bigg(\frac{j-1}{n}\bigg)^{z_1}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{z_2}\bigg(\frac{n-j}{n}\bigg)^{z_3}$$
$$=\frac{5!}{1!1!3!}\bigg(\frac{3-1}{5}\bigg)^1\bigg(\frac{1}{5}\bigg)^1\bigg(\frac{5-3}{5}\bigg)^3=0.1024$$

Let $Z$ denote the set of multinomial vectors resulting from possible realizations of $Y$ that meet the condition $Y_{\{i\}}=X_{\{j\}}$. The count of $Y_k<X_{\{j\}}$ (or $z_1$) in $Z$ can take the values $0...i-1$, and the count of $Y_k=X_{\{j\}}$ (or $z_2$) in $Z$ can take the values $(i-z_1)...(n-z_1)$, resulting in $|Z|=i\cdot(n-i+1)$.

The probability that the $j^{\text{th}}$ smallest element of $X$ is also the $i^{\text{th}}$ smallest element of $Y$ is

$$P(Y_{\{i\}}=X_{\{j\}})=\sum_{l=0}^{i\cdot(n-i+1)}P(Z_l)$$

Illustrating with $n=5$, $i=2$, and $j=3$ (showing counts of each event):

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
 l & Y_k<X_{\{j\}} & Y_k=X_{\{j\}} & Y_k>X_{\{j\}} & P(Z_l)\\\hline
 1 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 2.56\cdot10^{-2} \\\hline
 2 & 0 & 3 & 2 & 1.28\cdot10^{-2} \\\hline
 3 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 3.20\cdot10^{-3} \\\hline
 4 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 3.20\cdot10^{-4} \\\hline
 5 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1.02\cdot10^{-1} \\\hline
 6 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 7.68\cdot10^{-2} \\\hline
 7 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2.56\cdot10^{-2} \\\hline
 8 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 3.20\cdot10^{-3} 
\end{array}

As an R function:

```
pnij <- function(n, i, j) {
  if (j == 1) {
    eq <- i:n
    gt <- (n - i):0
    sum(exp(gt*log(n - j) - lgamma(eq + 1) - lgamma(gt + 1)))*exp(lgamma(n + 1) - n*log(n))
  } else if (j == n) {
    lt <- 0:(i - 1)
    eq <- n:(n - i + 1)
    sum(exp(lt*log(j - 1) - lgamma(lt + 1) - lgamma(eq + 1)))*exp(lgamma(n + 1) - n*log(n))
  } else {
    lt <- rep(0:(i - 1), each = n - i + 1)
    gt <- rep((n - i):0, i)
    eq <- n - lt - gt
    sum(exp(lt*log(j - 1) + gt*log(n - j) - lgamma(lt + 1) - lgamma(eq + 1) - lgamma(gt + 1)))*exp(lgamma(n + 1) - n*log(n))
  }
}
```

The following snippet demonstrates the function with a sanity check using $n=5$. First, enumerate all $n^n$ permutations of `1:5`, with repetition. After sorting each permutation, tabulate the count of each value `1:5` over all permutations.

```
library(RcppAlgos) # for permuteGeneral
library(Rfast) # for rowSort and colTabulate

n <- 5L

# get counts of each value 1:n at each position of the full set of sorted
# permutations with repetition
x <- t(colTabulate(rowSort(permuteGeneral(n, n, TRUE))))
# probabilities
x/n^n
#>         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]
#> [1,] 0.67232 0.24992 0.06752 0.00992 0.00032
#> [2,] 0.26272 0.40032 0.24992 0.08032 0.00672
#> [3,] 0.05792 0.25952 0.36512 0.25952 0.05792
#> [4,] 0.00672 0.08032 0.24992 0.40032 0.26272
#> [5,] 0.00032 0.00992 0.06752 0.24992 0.67232

# calculate the same probabilities using pnij 
y <- diag(0, n)
for (i in 1:n) for (j in 1:n) y[i, j] <- pnij(n, i, j)
y
#>         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]
#> [1,] 0.67232 0.24992 0.06752 0.00992 0.00032
#> [2,] 0.26272 0.40032 0.24992 0.08032 0.00672
#> [3,] 0.05792 0.25952 0.36512 0.25952 0.05792
#> [4,] 0.00672 0.08032 0.24992 0.40032 0.26272
#> [5,] 0.00032 0.00992 0.06752 0.24992 0.67232
all.equal(x/n^n, y)
#> [1] TRUE
```

For $n=20$:

```
n <- 20L
y <- diag(0, n)
system.time(for (i in 1:n) for (j in 1:n) y[i, j] <- pnij(n, i, j))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>       0       0       0

image(1:n, 1:n, y, xlab = "i", ylab = "j")
```

[image]

Comment: You lost me on the very first sentence. Why does comparing x and y result in a multinomial distribution. Please clarify and provide proof for your statements

Comment: I expanded on the examples and tried to clarify.

Comment: I noticed a typo in the first illustration. It was for $j=2$ rather than $j=3$. I updated it to reflect $j=3$.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have now understood your solution and it makes a lot of sense to me. I'm still not 100% sure what is l in your solution. In my understanding, Z should be parameterized by 2 indices, for example z1 and z2. Anyway, thanks a lot, i think i can take it from here

Comment: Glad the clarifications helped. Yes, $l$ is simply the index of the unique combinations of ($z_1$, $z_2$) that satisfy the constraint. But the order of the elements of $Z$ are not important. The motivation behind using $l$ was to show how the probability of interest is the sum of the probabilities of the $i\cdot(n-i+1)$ elements of $Z$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think this is sufficient to answer the question I have posed

Answer (score 2):

In summary, we can formulate a recurrence relation for this problem and then solve it using dynamic programming. Suppose the length of $X$ is $n$, and the i-th smallest number in $X$ is denoted as $X_i$. We are asked to find the probability of $X_i$ being the j-th smallest element in $Y$.

Assume that we have already selected $(n-a)$ numbers into $Y$, and we still need to choose `a` more numbers. In the numbers already selected, there are $y$ numbers strictly smaller than $X_i$ and $z$ numbers strictly greater than $X_i$.

For the boundary conditions, if $y > j-1$ or $z > n - j$, then the probability must be zero. If $a = 0$, the probability is $1$ (because the selection process has been completed at this point). For the purpose of simplification in our recurrence, let's denote $b = j - 1 - y$ and $c = n - j - z$. You can consider b and c as some form of quotas. The probability of achieving the goal at this point is denoted as $d(a,b,c)$.

When selecting an element from X, there are three possibilities:

1. The element is $X_i$. The probability of this situation is $\frac{1}{n}$, and the state moves to $d(a-1,b,c)$.
2. The element is strictly less than $X_i$. The probability of this situation is $\frac{i-1}{n}$, and the state moves to $d(a-1,b-1,c)$.
3. The element is strictly greater than $X_i$. The probability of this situation is $\frac{n-i}{n}$, and the state moves to $d(a-1,b,c-1)$.

So, we have $d(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{n} \times d(a-1, b, c) + \frac{i-1}{n} \times d(a-1, b-1, c) + \frac{n-i}{n} \times d(a-1, b, c-1)$.

The answer we ultimately want to solve is equal to $d(n, j-1, n-j)$.

The python code implementation is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def solve(n, i, j):
    d = -np.ones((n+1,n+1,n+1), np.float64)
    def dp(a, b, c):
        if a < 0 or b < 0 or c < 0:
            return 0
        if a == 0:
            return 1
        if d[a,b,c] >= 0:
            return d[a,b,c]
        d[a,b,c] = 1/n * dp(a-1, b, c) + (i-1)/n * dp(a-1, b-1, c) + (n-i)/n * dp(a-1, b, c-1)
        return d[a,b,c]
    return dp(n, j-1, n-j)

n = 20
ans = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        ans[i-1,j-1] = solve(n, i, j)

plt.imshow(ans, origin='lower')
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 20, 1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(1, 20, 1))
plt.savefig('prob.png')
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(np.log(ans), origin='lower')
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 20, 1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(1, 20, 1))
plt.savefig('logprob.png')
```

I have obtained results that are identical to your random experiment: [prob.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zLt7.png)

The closed-form solution to this problem should also exist, which I speculate is some form involving combinations.
As for the symmetry of $i$ and $j$, it can also be proven using mathematical induction with the recurrence, and I leave this as an exercise here.

---

Here are additional proofs of the termination condition.

We can assure that when we reach the termination condition `a==0` successfully, the following propositions must hold:

1. `b>=0 and c>=0`. Otherwise, the program will enter the first branch (`a < 0 or b < 0 or c < 0`).
2. $X_i$ is selected into $Y$ at least once. To prove this, let the number of times $X_i$ is selected be $k$, then we have $(j-1-b)+(n-j-c)+k=n$, from which it can be inferred that $k=b+c+1\geq 1$.
3. $X_i$ is exactly equal to the j-th smallest element in $Y$, because at this time the $(j-b)$th to $(j+c)$th elements in Y, from smallest to largest, are all equal to $X_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It did not even occur to me to try out dynamical programming, but your approach seems promising. It will take me some time to work through your solution. I will get back as soon as I have understood it.

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to ask me if you need further explanations.

Comment: I now understand your answer. I have a few concerns. Most importantly, there is a 4th possibility that is not mentioned. What if there were no elements i in Y, then the next element happened to be i, and it happened to fall into the right place? I found the extra term to income l involve a trinomial distribution, would be good to check. Further, I'm not sure about your boundary condition p(a=0)=1. Why does selecting all elements imply that the condition is met?

Comment: I understand your concerns. Due to the length limitations of comments on StackExchange, I have added the proof of the termination condition to the revised answer.